# array-valued array indices

Tags: fortran

I've just stumbled upon the fact that compiler lets me use integer arrays as indices to other arrays. For example:

```
  implicit none

  real*8 :: a(3), b(2)
  integer :: idx(2)

  a=1.d0
  idx=(/1,2/)

  b = a(idx)
  print*,shape(b) 
  print*,b
  print*

  end
```

Given the fact that this seems to work with both gfortan and a PGI compiler, I'm wondering if this a language feature rather than something compiler just lets me out with. I would appreciate if somebody more knowledgeable than me can comment if this is really a language feature.

And if it is, than I'd appreciate if somebody would spell out the exact language rules of how such constructions are interpreted in multidimensional case, like here:

```
  implicit none
  real*8  :: aa(3,3), bb(2,2)
  integer :: idx(2)

  do i=1,3 ; do j=1,3
    aa(i,j) = 1.d0*(i+j)
  enddo; enddo

  bb=aa(idx,idx)
  print*,shape(bb)
  print*,bb

  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is.

The final draft of the Fortran 2008 standard, ISO/IEC JTC 1/SC 22/WG 5/N1830, ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1801-N1850/N1830.pdf says on page 84

4.8 Construction of array values

...

6 If an ac-value is an array expression, the values of the elements of the expression, in array element order (6.5.3.2), specify the corresponding sequence of elements of the array constructor.

Example

```
real, dimension(20) :: b
...

k = (/3, 1, 4/)
b(k) = 0.0      ! section b(k) is a rank-one array with shape (3) and
                !  size 3. (0.0 is assigned to b(1), b(3), and b(4).)
```

The rules you can see directly from your code

```
implicit none
  real*8  :: aa(3,3), bb(2,2)
  integer :: idx(2),i,j,k
  idx=(/3, 2/)
  k=0
  do i=1,3 ; do j=1,3
    k=k+1
    aa(i,j) = aa(i,j)+1.d0*k
  enddo; enddo
  write(*,*),shape(aa)
  write(*,'(3G24.6,2X)') aa
  bb=aa(idx,idx)
  print*,shape(bb)
  write(*,'(2G24.6,2X)'),bb
  end
```

Output:

> ```
>        3           3
>          1.00000                 4.00000                 7.00000    
>          2.00000                 5.00000                 8.00000    
>          3.00000                 6.00000                 9.00000    
>        2           2
>          9.00000                 6.00000    
>          8.00000                 5.00000
> ```